# Uploading file to device takes too long

Tags: android

I have my Nexus 5 lollipop connected via USB for app debug/development, when I hit the Run App icon and wait, very often I have to disconnect and reconnect in order to get the process going after I see this Run screen for too long. I tried Clean Project for no avail, Any thing I could do to fix this?
Thank you

> Waiting for device.
>   Target device: lge-nexus_5-0112121212125e
>   Uploading file
>       local path: C:\Users\Jack\AndroidStudioProjects\Five\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>       remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.jack.five

Comment: How big is your apk?  Is your USB cable connection perhaps flaky?  You might try a new cable.

Comment: Please provide some more info about what IDE are you using. It could be that you have outdate drivers or cheap Chinese USB cable

Comment: I agree with the other comments. The usb cable can make a huge difference.

Comment: It is the USB cable that came with the phone. I do not see any brand/logo on it. It is snug fit. I am using Android Studio and the apk file is  1081kb